# Two Leonardos on one USB hub - not working properly

Tags: c++, arduino-leonardo, usb

I have two Arduino Leonardos here. They do different things, but basically they both emulate a keyboard. Here is an example:

```
const byte SWITCH = 12;

void setup ()
  {
  Keyboard.begin();
  pinMode (SWITCH, INPUT_PULLUP);
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {
  if (digitalRead (SWITCH) == LOW)
    {
    Keyboard.println ("foo");
    delay (2000);
    }
  }
```

Now I program a second Leonardo with the same code but send "bar" rather than "foo".

Now if I plug these into my PC (running Ubuntu 14.04) using different USB ports, everything works. When the switch is closed I see "foo" and "bar" being typed into whatever application is open.

However ...

If I plug them both into a D-Link 4-port USB hub (model DUB-1340) only the first one works. The other is ignored.

Doing `lsusb` shows this (along with other irrelevant devices):

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 040: ID 2341:8036 Arduino SA Leonardo (CDC ACM, HID)
Bus 003 Device 039: ID 2341:8036 Arduino SA Leonardo (CDC ACM, HID)
```

This happens in both cases (if they are both in the USB hub or not).

---

### My question

Is this proper behaviour that two Leonardos on a USB hub fail to both work? (Perhaps you aren't supposed to plug two identical USB devices in at once).

Or, is this a bug in either:

- The Leonardo USB interface?
- My USB hub?

---

### Update

Further testing revealed that the setup worked OK when plugged into my Mac running OS/X.

Then I went back to Ubuntu and it worked as well! However a mouse that I had plugged into the USB hub now stopped working!

Further investigation reveals that the fourth port on my USB hub is faulty in some way. If I swap the mouse and the Leonardo the Leonardo works but not the mouse.

Following Majenko's suggestion:

> You can try running usb-devices from the usbutils package (should be already installed since lsusb is in the same package) and look for the two Leonardo blocks.

First one:

```
T:  Bus=03 Lev=02 Prnt=50 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 66 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=02(commc) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2341 ProdID=8036 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Arduino LLC
S:  Product=Arduino Leonardo
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_acm
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_acm
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
```

Second one:

```
T:  Bus=03 Lev=02 Prnt=50 Port=03 Cnt=04 Dev#= 72 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=02(commc) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2341 ProdID=8036 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Arduino LLC
S:  Product=Arduino Leonardo
C:  #Ifs= 0 Cfg#= 0 Atr= MxPwr=
cat: /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/3-3/3-3.4/3-*:?.*/bInterfaceNumber: No such file or directory
cat: /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/3-3/3-3.4/3-*:?.*/bAlternateSetting: No such file or directory
cat: /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/3-3/3-3.4/3-*:?.*/bNumEndpoints: No such file or directory
cat: /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/3-3/3-3.4/3-*:?.*/bInterfaceClass: No such file or directory
cat: /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/3-3/3-3.4/3-*:?.*/bInterfaceSubClass: No such file or directory
cat: /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/3-3/3-3.4/3-*:?.*/bInterfaceProtocol: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/usb-devices: line 79: printf: (none): invalid number
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=() Sub= Prot= Driver=
```

---

### Tentative conclusion

Perhaps I somehow damaged that USB port by drawing too much current during testing at some earlier point.

Although ... now the mouse is working in the port where it was not working before, and the Leonardo has stopped working in the 3rd port, when it was previously not working in the 4th port.

Those error messages above must be relevant, but I don't know enough about it to say in what way.

Comment: What OS are you using? You could try changing the PID on one of them.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04. See updated question.

Comment: Are you using the external power for the hub or drawing power from the bus?

Comment: I was using external power on Ubuntu, but drawing from the bus on the Mac, as it was fiddly to move the power wire.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason I can think of that would stop it working as it should.

`lsusb` is showing both the devices, so they are being detected by the kernel.

You can try running `usb-devices` from the *usbutils* package (should be already installed since `lsusb` is in the same package) and look for the two Leonardo blocks. You should get two blocks like this:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=03 Prnt=07 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 11 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2341 ProdID=0036 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Arduino LLC
S:  Product=USB IO Board    
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_acm
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_acm
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
```

The important bit is the `I:` lines - they show the individual USB interfaces and what kernel driver has been associated with them.   For the keyboard, of course, it's the last entry, which is assigned to the `usbhid` driver.

Another good diagnostic is `dmesg -w`

Run that with both Leonardos disconnected.  Plug one in and it should show it registering as a USB device.  A few moments later you should get a pair of lines like:

```
[ 2106.937086] input: Arduino LLC USB IO Board     as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.1/1-1.4.1:1.2/0003:2341:0036.0006/input/input21
[ 2106.990523] hid-generic 0003:2341:0036.0006: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [Arduino LLC USB IO Board    ] on usb-0000:00:1a.7-1.4.1/input2
```

That is the board being associated with an input device (in this case input 2).

Repeat it with the second Leonardo and see if the same appears, but this time with a higher input number (it would be 3 on mine if I had a second Leonardo).

The fact that the two Leonardos work together normally means that they should be working fine in any arrangement, so if the OS is seeing it all fine but the data isn't getting through, then my money is on the hub.  It looks quite a new hub, so it may have a few bugs in it that are yet to be ironed out.

USB devices are identified to the drivers using the VID and PID, but to the kernel the USB device is just a chain of bus/port numbers.  For instance my Leonardo above is identified as:

```
1-1.4.1
```

That's USB bus 1, downstream port 1 (root hub - normally only has 1 port), which connects to a hub (the one built into the computer to drive multiple ports) which then has downstream port 4 connecting to a hub (on my desk) which then has downstream port 1 connecting to the device.  Nothing else can be connected to that same combination of downstream ports - it's physically impossible, so it's uniquely identified.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, see amended question.